# VBA Code to click Play Activity button in a Web page

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeking some help on how I can click the "Play Activity button" in our Global Productivity Hub in our office using excel VBA. I'm creating an attendance log in tool with lunch and break trackers. Once the employee click Log In with tool that I created, the GPH site will launch and will logged them in, the same thing with Log Out. However, I'm having difficulty in controlling the break and lunch button of GPH site using the tool that I created. I cannot find the correct elements to integrate to my vba code. I hope someone can help me with this. Please see below the HTML code of that particular button and the image.

```html
<tr class="top-five">
    <td title="Play Activity" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle play-activity" data-toggle="tooltip" data-team-id="e9575e8b-4682-734c-b28d-b1ee5532a8ce" data-activity-id="e0728017-a4fa-ef4b-91a6-262e5418a134" data-team-name="Technology Team"> </td>
 <td> 
   <span title="Break Activities" class="act-ellipsis" data-toggle="tooltip">
<span class="ellip ellip-line"> Break Activities </span>

</span>
 Break
</td> 

<td title="Favorite" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" data-toggle="tooltip" data-activity-id="e0728017-a4fa-ef4b-91a6-262e5418a134"></td>

</tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot is too small to see any details, but basically, it works like this.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Make sure you set references to...

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft Internet Controls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `Break Activities` element with a CSS selector of:

```
span[title='Break Activities']
```

That reads as attribute `title` with value `"Break Activities"` within `span` tag.

---

CSS query in action:

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

```
IE.document.querySelector("span[title='Break Activities']").Click
```

Outline implementation:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "yourURL"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend '<== Loop until loaded

        'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,3) '< Additional wait for element to become avaiable may be required
         .document.querySelector("span[title='Break Activities']").Click

        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With

End Sub
```

---

[`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method:

The `Document` method `querySelector()` returns the first `Element` within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

Syntax: `element = document.querySelector(selectors);` <== note the ";" is not used in VBA